# Windows 10: Blue Screen Issues

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Alright, well I'm having issues with Blue Screens that have been coming and going.
The first one is:
Kernal_Data_Inpage_Error(HTTP.sys)

The other is:
Memory_Management

Here is my computer build:
http://pcpartpicker.com/p/CrLg7P

Here are My Crash_Dumps: https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=E42D1592FBEBAEDC&resid=E42D1592FBEBAEDC%21462&authkey=ABJV4LjB-dCKg0c

Comment: Sounds like memory failure. Have you run memtest86?

Comment: Kernal_Data_Inpage_Error often indicate HDD issues. Check the disks. Also upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump to OneDrive and post the share link here.

Comment: Here are my dumps... https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=E42D1592FBEBAEDC&resid=E42D1592FBEBAEDC%21462&authkey=ABJV4LjB-dCKg0c

I'll try Memtest86 Soon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dump my guess was correct. Data which are reloaded from the pagefile are corrupted while Windows tries to read and uncompress the data:

> Memory Manager detected corruption of a pagefile page while performing
>   an in-page operation. **The data read from storage does not match the
>   original data written. This indicates the data was corrupted by** the
>   storage stack, or **device hardware**.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!MiValidatePagefilePageHash
02 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
03 nt!MiIssueHardFault
04 nt!MmAccessFault
05 nt!KiPageFault
06 nt!RtlDecompressBufferXpressLz
07 nt!RtlDecompressBufferEx
08 nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmSinglePageCopy
```

Check the [HDD for SMART errors](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) and also try a different SATA cable or a different SATA port.

Comment: Here's another that just came up:
Critical_Process_Died

Comment: What am I looking for on this thing? Both SSD and HDD are saying GOOD with their statuses...